Confluence and beta-reduction
I am studying lambda calculus at university and I came across beta-reduction. I don't know if I don't understand confluence, and beta-reduction, but the term (x.y.x)(z.z)(w.w) seem to give either (y.(z.z))(w.w) which then reduces to z.z or (x.y.x)(w.w) which reduces to y.(w.w) which seems irreducible. Shouldn't I get the same answer for any route I take? It seems like I am doing something wrong... Can I please have some help?
Thanks in advance.

Your second reduction is incorrect. By convention, function application associates to the left, so (x.y.x)(z.z)(w.w) must be interpreted as ((x.y.x)(z.z))(w.w) and not as (x.y.x)((z.z)(w.w)).  Your second reduction seems to use the second (wrong) interpretation.

Oh, perfect! Thank you!
